# how to delete properties in array using JSON_MODIFY in sql server

Tags: sql, arrays, json, sql-server

I have a complex json stored in a `varchar(max)` column. I have an array of strings in the json.

```
myArray: ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']
```

I am running the following update query to delete property `two` from the array above using `JSON_MODIFY`.

```
UPDATE MYTABLE SET MYJSONCOL = JSON_MODIFY(MYJSONCOL, '$.section[0].subsection[7].myArray[1]', null) WHERE MYID = 'ABCD';
```

However, the query results in:

```
myArray: ['one', null, 'three', 'four']
```

But I want it to be:

```
myArray: ['one', 'three', 'four']
```

How do I achieve this?

I tried adding `lax` in front of the path. But I got the same result i.e. `null` instead of property being completely removed.

```
UPDATE MYTABLE SET MYJSONCOL = JSON_MODIFY(MYJSONCOL, 'lax $.section[0].subsection[7].myArray[1]', null) WHERE MYID = 'ABCD';
```

How can I completely remove a property from a json array using `JSON_MODIFY`.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am aware `JSON_MODIFY()` does not support removing items from an array. One workaround is to expand the array using `OPENJSON()`, remove the items you need to, then rebuild it using `STRING_AGG()` and then replace your full array with the newly create one.

It feels a bit hacky, but it does work:

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#T', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #T;

CREATE TABLE #T (MyJSONCol VARCHAR(MAX));
INSERT #T (MyJSONCol)
VALUES ('{ "SomeProperty": "SomeValue", "myArray": ["one", "two", "three", "four"] }');


SELECT  *
FROM    #T AS t;

UPDATE  t
SET     t.MyJSONCol = JSON_MODIFY(t.MyJSONCol, '$.myArray', JSON_QUERY(oj.MyNewArray))
FROM    #T AS t
        CROSS APPLY 
        (   SELECT  CONCAT('[', STRING_AGG(CONCAT('"', oj.Value, '"'), ','), ']')
            FROM    OPENJSON(t.MyJSONCol, '$.myArray') AS oj
            WHERE   oj.[Key] <> 1
        ) AS oj (MyNewArray);

SELECT  *
FROM    #T AS t;
```

**[Example on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/qaMmXI34)**

---

**ADDENDUM**

The above will fall down if any of the items in the array are objects, to get around this you need to check if the item is JSON first, and if so, don't concatenate the quotes to the value:

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#T', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #T;

CREATE TABLE #T (MyJSONCol VARCHAR(MAX));
INSERT #T (MyJSONCol)
VALUES 
('{ "SomeProperty": "SomeValue", "myArray": ["one", "two", "three", "four"] }'),
('{ "SomeProperty": "SomeValue", "myArray": ["one", {"two": "SomeValue"}, {"three": "SomeValue"}, "four"] }'),
('{ "SomeProperty": "SomeValue", "myArray": [{"one": "SomeValue"}, {"two": "SomeValue"}, {"three": "SomeValue"}, {"four": ["one", "two", "three"]}] }');


SELECT  *
FROM    #T AS t;

UPDATE  t
SET     MyJSONCol = JSON_MODIFY(t.MyJSONCol, '$.myArray', JSON_QUERY(oj.MyNewArray))
FROM    #T AS t
        CROSS APPLY 
        (   SELECT  CONCAT('[', STRING_AGG(CASE WHEN ISJSON(oj.Value) = 1 THEN oj.Value ELSE CONCAT('"', oj.Value, '"') END, ','), ']')
            FROM    OPENJSON(t.MyJSONCol, '$.myArray') AS oj
            WHERE   oj.[Key] <> 1
        ) AS oj (MyNewArray);

SELECT  *
FROM    #T AS t;
```

**[Example on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/0X68AYAU)**

Comment: Thanks for this. Is there a way to completely remove the whole array? That is '{ "SomeProperty": "SomeValue", "myArray": ["one", "two", "three", "four"] }'  after array deletion should result in '{ "SomeProperty": "SomeValue" }' and not '{ "SomeProperty": "SomeValue", null }' ... The DB I want to update may not have compatibility level 150. Hence the question about completely removing the array.

Comment: @gotqn please check my updated comment.

Comment: @Vicky there's no issue with removing entire properties using `JSON_MODIFY()`, so `JSON_MODIFY(t.MyJSONCol, '$.myArray', NULL)` should work fine, the limitation is with removing items from an array, which is what requires the work around. If you do need a workaround that works in SQL Server 2016, you can use the old `FOR XML PATH()` trick to rebuild the array rather than string_agg, so you can still remove a single item even without compatibility level 150: [example on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Q5E5hhkV)

Answer (score 0):

Try this to remove the whole array:

```
DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
(
    [Project] VARCHAR(MAX)
);

INSERT INTO @DataSource ([Project])
VALUES ('{"SomeProperty": "SomeValue","myArray":["one", "two", "three", "four"]}');


UPDATE @DataSource 
SET [Project] = JSON_MODIFY([Project], '$.myArray', NULL)


SELECT [Project]
FROM @DataSource
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I thought this will also result like my original question.